# numpy-1.12.1+mkl-cp27-cp27m-win32 (1).whl is not a supported wheel on this platform

Tags: python, numpy

While doing pip install for a "numpy" package, I get this..

numpy-1.12.1+mkl-****cp27**-cp27m-win32** (1).whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Going by the platform output below, it should work.Any suggestions?

> > > ```
> > > import pip; print(pip.pep425tags.get_supported())
> > > ```

[('**cp27', 'cp27m**', 'win32'), ('cp27', 'none', 'win32'), ('py2', 'none', 'win32'), ('cp27', 'none', 'any'), ('cp2', 'none
', 'any'), ('py27', 'none', 'any'), ('py2', 'none', 'any'), ('py26', 'none', 'any'), ('py25', 'none', 'any'), ('py24', '
none', 'any'), ('py23', 'none', 'any'), ('py22', 'none', 'any'), ('py21', 'none', 'any'), ('py20', 'none', 'any')]

> > > ```
> > > import platform;platform.architecture()
> > > ```
> > >
> > > ('**32bit', 'WindowsPE**')

Comment: Remove the `(1)` from the filename.

Comment: Works like a charm now. But, I feel rather stupid :). Thought it only looks for the package content and not its name